# Question about もらう

Tags: grammar

As I learned, we can use もらう like this 「私は彼女に弁当を作ってもらいました。」, where noun before に(から) - giver and は(etc.) - reciever. But I saw sentence like

> 「もっとも・・・・・・そんな風になっちまった以上は、因縁なんざ意味がないだろう。悪いが**俺に譲ってもらうぜ**」
>    and the second one - [image]

Where noun before に is not giver(though in second case it's には, so I'm not sure), but as far as I can tell - receiver. Can somebody please explain this part to me, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 私は彼女に弁当を作ってもらいました, 
([①私は][②彼女に][③弁当を作って]もらいました)
①私 is the receiver and ②彼女 is the giver.  
ie. ②彼女 does ③お弁当を作る for ①私.

In 悪いが俺に譲ってもらうぜ,
(悪いが[①俺は][②お前に][③それを俺に譲って]もらうぜ) 
①俺 is the receiver and ②お前 is the giver. 
ie. ②お前 do ③それを俺に譲る for ①俺.

In [幼馴染]{おさななじみ}たちにはここで自由に過ごしてもらうようにしている,
([①菩乃花さんや自分(=the writer?)は][②幼馴染たちに(は=topical particle)][③ここで自由に過ごして]もらうようにしている) 
①菩乃花さんや自分 are the receivers and ②幼馴染たち are the givers. 
ie. ②幼馴染たち do ③ここで自由に過ごす for ①菩乃花さんや自分. 
(菩乃花さんや自分 want 幼馴染たち to do ここで自由に過ごす.)

Comment: In the second example, how does `俺に` become `[①俺は][②お前に]`?

Comment: @snailboat Both ①俺は and ②お前に are left out in the original sentence. The 俺に is still there in ③俺に譲って. (それを is left out/implied too.)

Comment: Oh, I see!  I missed that 俺に was in 3.

Answer (score 2):

～てもらう can also mean "to have s.o. do sth.". In your first example

> 悪いが俺に譲ってもらうぜ。
>   Sorry, but I'll have you hand it over to me.

This usage obviously derives from the usage you already know, where もらう means "to receive".

Similarly for your second example:

> ここで自由に過ごしてもらうようにしてる。
>   We are having them move around freely here.